# Import errors after plugin updates for Python(x,y)

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, pandas, pythonxy

I am using Python(x,y) (version 2.7.3.1) with the Spyder ide. Everything was working perfectly until I updated the plugins. I updated Pandas to version 0.12.0-7, matplotlib to version 1.3.1-4, and numpy to version 1.6.2. I did this by downloading the plugins on the Python(x,y) page and double clicking on the executable file.

Now I get errors when I try to import Matplotlib and pandas.

When I try to import matplotlib, the error is:

```
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

When I try to import Pandas, the error I get is:

```
numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling.
```

Other stackflow questions ask how matplotlib and pandas were installed, but I'm not sure how to answer that question given that I used plugins.

ps: I'm running Windows Vista Home Premium

Comment: Maybe this can help you install these packages in an easier way? https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Answer (score 0):

I've solved part of this problem. It turns out that I hadn't actually installed the latest plugin for numpy. Once I did that, I got a new error about datautil. I installed that using this blog post: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.xy.devel/month=20130601.

Now I can import pandas. Still working on Matplotlib.